# Applescript works as native in FMP12 but not as calculated. Why?

Tags: applescript, filemaker, quicktime

Why this works perfectly called from a button as a "NATIVE APPLESCRIPT"

```
set film to (choose file with prompt "Choose input file.")'s POSIX path
set frame_number to 606 --- *this is an example frame_number*

set fps to 25

tell application id "com.apple.quicktimeplayer" -- QuickTime Player 7

    tell (open film as POSIX file)

        set current time to frame_number / fps * time scale

    end tell

end tell
```

and gives this error: `Can’t make time scale into type number.`

My modification as follows

```
Let ( mac_path = Right ( Substitute ( ClipsWork::Media Path; "/"; ":"); Length (ClipsWork::Media Path) - 1); 

"set frame_number to " & ClipsWork::FPS_D & ¶ & 
"set fps to 25"  & ¶ & 

"tell application \"Quicktime 7\"" & ¶ & 
    "activate" & ¶ & 

    "open " & Quote ( mac_path ) & ¶ & 

    "set current time to frame_number "  & ¶ & 

    "set the dimensions of movie 1 to {480, 270}" & ¶ & 

"end tell"

)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Regards

Dan

Answer (score 0):

I can see that both extracts are doing the same thing, but they are slightly different. The easiest check is to paste second extract into Data Viewer.

The difference is in this line:

```
set current time to frame_number / fps * time scale
```

vs

```
"set current time to frame_number "  & ¶ &
```

The division to fps variable and multiplication by time scale are missing.

Looking at the error message, it sounds as time scale is in incorrect data type.

Comment: Thanks for the attention to my post. With some help I was able to fix the script as follows:

Comment: You do not have to use ":" notation in AppleScript anymore, look up POSIX   in AppleScript.

Comment: If "Exodo" volume is mounted and not local, you might be loosing the network connection at some point. I have  a similar problem, where the script runs for days and loads files from the shared volumes hundreds of times but sometimes fails once/twice in every run.  The way around it is to check if the volume is mounted and remount it again. In my case it is usually being locked by the overnight backup, so I introduced a delay to wait it out.

Comment: Thanks but as I am a newbie I don't know exactly how to fix the script to avoid the ":" problem. Each time I try to fix it I have to select the field even if there is only one table in the script so FMP12 will insert "tablename :: fieldname) and I have no ways to fix it. I even tried to adjust the script in TextWrangler just using the fieldname but as I past it in the Calculated text script FMP12 asks to reselect the proper field adding the table name. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what is the problem that you are having. When you insert tablename :: fieldname into your script, it will render to whatever value is in this field for current record. "::" just denotes the relationship and should not give you an error. If you only have one table and running the script from the layout based on this table, you should be able to remove "table::" from your calculation.

Comment: Looking again at the path you stored and used for the example - this will be parsed by calculation to Volumes:Exodo:Film_30_XI_12 XII:Whole_Files:Action_Proxy:MVI_3571.MOV. I believe the "Volumes" bit creates the problem as it is UNIX part of the filepath. Try to remove "Volumes:" (including : after), and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the attention to my post:

The script now works "randomly" as calculated script  both in Snow Leopard and in Mavericks.

With some help (I am a newbies in Applescript). 
This is the script:

```
Let (
    mac_path = Right ( Substitute ( ClipsWork::Media Path; "/"; ":"); Length (ClipsWork::Media Path) - 1)
;
    "set frame_number to "  & ClipsWork::FPS_D & ¶ &
    "tell application \"QuickTime Player 7\"" & ¶ &
        "activate" & ¶ &
        "tell (open " & Quote ( mac_path ) & ")" & ¶ &
            "set current time to frame_number / 25 * time scale" & ¶ &
            "set dimensions to {480, 270}" & ¶ &
        "end tell" & ¶ &
    "end tell"
)
```

I was suggested to add another "tell" instruction after calling Quicktime so now it works.

However the script gives various errors "randomly" especially after working a few hours. As if the caches fill up leading to errors. I only have this application on and off the internet ...

This is more frequent in Mavericks. the error I get is on the Path data. It include ":" symbol hence the error is always "cannot get ":" after the identifier".

FMP12 adds the table name with the field in the scripts calculations and tables include ":".

How to solve this is beyond my understanding ... if anyone has ideas on tricking FMP12 please let me know.

This is the data in the FMP12 db;

In the same layout I have these fields with this data :

`ClipsWork::Media Path`

*returning this text: `/Volumes/Exodo/Film_30_XI_12 XII/Whole_Files/Action_Proxy/MVI_3571.MOV`*

`ClipsWork::FPS_D`

*returning this frame number : `1458`*

I have one table only but still this is the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, whenever I use AppleScript within FileMaker, I never used calculated scripts. Instead, to get information from one to the other I set global fields in FileMaker and then use AppleScript to get the contents of the global fields. So were I creating this solution, would use a script step to set a global field to the correct path (`Set Field[g_applescript_parameter]; "your calc"]`), followed by a `Perform AppleScript` that would look something like the following:

```
tell current record to set mac_path to cell "g_applescript_parameter"
...
tell application id "com.apple.quicktimeplayer" to open file mac_path
```

A major advantage of this is that it's much easier to troubleshoot a bug in the script within Apple's Script Editor (or even easier in [Script Debugger](http://www.latenightsw.com/)). Once you have it working there, a copy and paste brings it into FileMaker without modification (except, perhaps, in the case Script Editor, the need to remove `tell application "FileMaker"` blocks, Script Debugger can have AppleScript commands target a default application).